# how to implement a grpc client in lua at a bare minimum

Tags: lua, client, http2, grpc

I am trying to implement a grpc client in lua.After some exploration I think I need to

1)use a lua http2 library for the transport layer communication
2)prot0buf library for request and response decoding
3)mapping the [service](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/blob/master/protos/graphp/graphresponse.proto#L9) name in proto file to a http endpoint
4)sending the request and body as per the protocol.

I looked at the https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md.

So do you have any pointers that can help me in implementing a bare minimum working client which can invoke a grpc service such as a dgraph database (https://docs.dgraph.io/v0.7.5/clients/) .

thanks